# How do I get the results of one JOIN and THEN feed those into a separate join in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm trying to JOIN 2 tables ON a key like

```
SELECT column1,column2
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.t2id = t2.id
```

Now, I have a 3rd table that has a Foreign Key with t2's id that I want to join... When I do

```
LEFT JOIN 
   Table3 t3 ON t3.t2id = --<-------------- This is where I'm lost
```

I don't know if I should do `ON t3.t2id = t1.t2id` OR `ON t3.t2id = t2.id`

What I need is the list of t2ids which are still in the picture *after the first join*. However, it seems as though if I specify either of the above, it will just pull ids from the original table before the first join?

To clarify one more time: I'm trying to essentially do a `INNER JOIN` of Table1 and Table2, get the resulting table, then get the t2ids of those results and feed them into a final join such that the final result contains all of Table3's rows as well as the data from the first join

Comment: Final part of your question is unclear 'result contains all of Table3's rows as well as the data from the first join' you mean the inner join where in only the matching rows get fetched?

Answer (score 2):

You said: "final result contains all of Table3's rows as well as the data from the first join".

It means that you need

```
Table3 LEFT JOIN <previous results>
```

instead of

```
<previous results> LEFT JOIN Table3
```

The easiest way to write it is to use Common-Table Expressions:

```
WITH
CTE_InnerJoin
AS
(
    SELECT column1, column2, t1.t2id
    FROM 
        Table1 t1
        INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.t2id = t2.id
)
SELECT
    CTE_InnerJoin.column1
    ,CTE_InnerJoin.column2
    ,Table3....
FROM
    Table3
    LEFT JOIN CTE_InnerJoin ON CTE_InnerJoin.t2id = Table3.t2id
;
```

It doesn't matter what column you include in the CTE: `t1.t2id` or `t2.id`, the values in them are the same, because they are inner-joined together.

Answer (score 2):

JOINs already do exactly what you want. A `JOIN` *isn't* always between two tables. Frequently, it's between *the results of previous joins*.

```
SELECT column1,column2
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.t2id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN 
   Table3 t3 ON t3.t2id = t2.id
```

At the point at which you're writing the final `ON` clause here, what you're joining is *precisely* the results of the previous `INNER JOIN` on the left and the table `Table3` on the right. All of `t1`, `t2` and `t3` are in scope within the `ON` clause, but note that `t1` and `t2` are now both used as aliases into the same source of rows - the previous `INNER JOIN`.

As a further example, consider the "diamond join":

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    t1
      left join
    t2
      on
        t1.a = t2.b
      left join
    t3
      on
        t1.c = t3.d
      inner join
    t4
      on
        t2.e = t4.f OR
        t3.g = t4.h
```

This is a way of joining two tables (`t1` and `t4`) based on two alternative joins. Note that in the final `inner join`, what is on the "left" is the result of already joining tables `t1`, `t2` and `t3`.

Answer (score 0):

Join the table having foreign key with

Try this....

```
SELECT column1,column2
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.t2id = t2.id
LEFT join Table3 t3 ON t2.id=t3.t2id
```

Answer (score 0):

Or Like this.

```
    SELECT  t12.column1 ,
            t12.column2 ,
            t3.*
    FROM    ( 
              --- INNER JOIN of Table1 and Table2, get the resulting table,
              SELECT    t1.column1 ,
                        t2.column2 ,
                        t1.t2id  --- or t2.id doesn't matter because its inner join
              FROM      Table1 t1
                        INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.t2id = t2.id
            ) T12
            LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON t3.t2id = t1.t2id  --- then get the t2ids of those results 
                                                      --- and feed them into a final join

            --- if  you want to get all rows from Table3, Change LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON t3.t2id = T1.t2id 
            --- into  RIGHT JOIN Table3 T3 ON t3.t2id = T1.t2id
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want all rows from table 3 and those matching rows from table1 inner joined to table2 then you can use this syntax:

```
select t3.*,
column1, column2
from table3 t3
left join table2 t2
inner join table1 t1
on t1.t2id = t2.id
on t3.t2id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select t3.*, column1, column2
from 
table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.t2id = t2.id
right outer join table3 t3 on t3.t2id = t2.id
```

equvalent to

```
select t3.*, column1, column2
from 
table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.t2id = t2.id
right outer join table3 t3 on t3.t2id = t1.t2id
```